# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have the following statistical data below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tesflutter/constants/color_constant.dart';

class CardModel {
  String name;
  String cardBackground;
  Color bgColor;

  CardModel(this.name,this.cardBackground, this.bgColor);
}

List<CardModel> cards = cardData
    .map((item) => CardModel(
        item['name'],
        item['cardBackground'],
        item['bgColor']))
    .toList();

var cardData = [
  {
    "name": "Prambors",
    "cardBackground": 'assets/icons/mastercard_bg.svg',
    "bgColor": kMasterCardColor
  },
]
```

and this

```
child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 8),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: cards.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                    height: 175,
                    width: 220,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      color: cards[index].bgColor,
                    ),
                  );
                }),
```

when I call the data I get an error,
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.
how could this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but you can use `item['bgColor'] as Color`, like this

```
List<CardModel> cards = cardData
    .map((item) => CardModel(
          item['name'] as String,
          item['cardBackground'] as String,
          item['bgColor'] as Color,
        ))
    .toList();
```